# IOS: Is it normal behavior for AccessoryButtonTapped to cause immediate reload of tableview?

Tags: ios, delegates, tableview

I am trying to slow things down when an accessorybutton of a tableview is tapped in order to show an animation. When the accessory button is tapped, my use case is to remove the row from the tableview by changing a flag in core data. Before removing it, however, I want to insert a short animation.

I can't find anywhere in the code where it explicitly calls reloadData. So I am speculating that the accessoryButton tapped does this on its own or else the accessoryButtonTapped calls viewWillAppear which does have a tableview reloadData call. (For the record the data is coming from core data and I'm using an NSFetchedResultsController.)

Does accessoryButtonTapped call reloadData or viewWillAppear automatically? If so, is there anyway to slow things down to insert an animation?  Can't find anything on this in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614996-tableview?language=objc).

Edit:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     Items *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       NSNumber *touched= @1;
    NSNumber *notTouched = @0;
    if(([item.touched isEqual:touched]))
    {
        item.touched=notTouched;
        item.needsync=@1;
    }
    else
    {
        item.touched=touched;
        item.needsync=@1;
//Attempted Animation here        
        [self animateItemTouched:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] withItem:item];

    }

     self.managedObjectContext = [IDModel sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;
    NSError *error;
    if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

    [self createPackageAndSendToServer:item];    
    }
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error") }

     }
}
```

Comment: No, an accessory button tap only does whatever you have in the delegate method. Your fetched results controller is responsible for updating the table view. Please edit your question to show the relevant code

Comment: By delegate method, you mean - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;?

Comment: There's not much in method except saving the managed object context and save to the server. The server save does not seem to have any reload of the table. Does a save of the context reload table?

Comment: It is probably your fetched results controller delegate method that is updating your table view. Set breakpoints in those methods. They are probably being called when you change the managed object, not when you save it.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. So I need to do the animation beforehand. The animation takes place in the cell so my next problem is how to get the cell to redraw itself on its own. I tried just changing a label in the cell and then calling [cell setNeedsDisplay]; but it does nothing until the FRC methods (and cellforrow method) fire.

Comment: You can either get a reference to the cell using `cellForRowAt` and update the views directly or call `reloadRowsAt`

Comment: OK. Thx! I can now get the label to change but animation not working. Asked another question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129546/ios-force-tableview-cell-to-animate-change-on-tap